# Is there any reason not to use static class methods for a Service in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm building my first Angular 2 app using Ionic, and am building out a couple of services.  The tutorial doesn't use static methods, but to me, it seems that in my use case, static methods and properties are the way to go.  To NOT use static methods would be like this:

```
import {MyService} from "../services/MyService";
@Component({
  templateUrl:"page.html",
  providers: [MyService]
})

export class MyNewClass{
    constructor(private myService: MyService){}

    //to use:
    this.MyService.get()
}
```

VS

```
import {MyService} from "../services/MyService";
@Component({
  templateUrl:"page.html"
})

export class MyNewClass{
    constructor(){}

    //to use:
    MyService.get()
}
```

Now in my use case, `MyService` data doesn't change across the whole app.  I load up the data a single time, and need to use it all across the app.  I would like to have a static array in MyService that contains the info that all the other classes use.  The benefit to this, in my opinion, is that it is very clear that there is a single instance across the whole app - no guessing.  Also, I don't have to write `providers: [MyService]`, and don't have to inject it into the constructor, which I think would be a very good things as I don't want the constructor parameters to become unreadable due to length. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Seems to me like the standard argument applies: How do you test something that uses this service? Can you swap it out for a mock version?

Comment: @Niklas B. It seems like it would be pretty easy to test - you just hardcode in some data and return that. However I don't have much experience with testing frameworks, so I would appreciate you telling me if/why that would be a problem.

Comment: I guess if your service is configurable in a way that it can return mock responses to requests made to it, then yes, the components that use it are testable. But then the service itself seems to be overly complex

Answer (score 3):

If you really hate `providers: [MyService]`, though not really an advised practice,  you could bootstrap it: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyService])`.

Some of the cons against static methods are:

1. that is not *standard idiom/style* in services: you'd get people asking what's special in this case to make you write it like that -- also you could have a harder time trying to follow the [Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide).

   - Maybe you should consider implementing standalone functions and exporting them

     ```
     export function getStuff() { ... }
     export function foo() { ... }
     ```

     And then

     ```
     import { getStuff, foo } from './shared/stuff';
     ```
2. in general, static stuff is just harder (or less natural) to replace in code, either in test environments or really just in runtime (think polymorphism).

Now, since those reasons aren't really a technical *block* (as, for example, the need for any angular-injected functionality in your service would be), right now you could say it boils down to opinion.

So, if your testing (aka technical) needs are met, talk to your team and use what everyone thinks is best (aka solving opinion matters old school way). If they are OK with the non-standard way of testing and using that service, then go for it (as long as it works...).